# Server Side Blazor - Claims Transformation - AddDbContext Scope best practices

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I am developing a server-side Blazor application on which I need to transform the Claim through a service to add the user roles from the database. I have configured the AddDbContext as suggested by Microsoft documentation (ServiceLifetime.Transient) and the Claim transformation service as Transient. the dbContext is injected into the Claim Transformation service and I get this error: **An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseSqlServer' call**

Any idea how should I configure this  to prevent this error?

Comment: What do you need the DBContext for in your Claim transformation service ? Could you please post your code.

Comment: Don't register anything as Transient of it implements IDisposable, the object never gets garbage collected. Could you give me a link to the doc so I can report it?